# How to add a info pulled from an API to a Google Map infowindow?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am using a film festival api. This api works with film ids and it gives the json data according to that id. in that data there is film name, film url, film length etc. what i did is that i wrote all the ids under each country marker since I would like to show which movie is coming from which country. Now i can only see the ids in information windows, not the data that i want (filmName and filmUrl). Do you know how somehow to combine them ?

Each marker should open a infowindow with the data for that marker.
number of infowindows= number of markers

Is there anybody know how to help?
Thank you in advance.

```
var ourMarkers =[marker1, marker2, marker3];

for (var x = 0; x < ourMarkers.length; x++)
{
    var ourMarker = ourMarkers[x];
    for (var i=0;i<ourMarker.customInfo.length;i++){        
         $.ajax({
            url: "http://blabla"+ourMarker.customInfo[i]+"/format/json/API-Key/YQ8UtQp5fCQIDAknJLVXZLWvAcsWjpa86XPml3eH",
            dataType: "json",
            header: {'X-API-KEY': 'blabla'},
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.filmName_en, result.filmInfoURL);
            },
            done:function(result){
            //console.log(result);
            }
        }); 
    }   
    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+ ourMarker.customInfo+'</div>';
    bindInfoWindow(ourMarker, map, infoWindow, contentString);
}
```

Comment: at least mention what kind of More information you need from API and if you are having problem getting those information or you just don't know how to, Important relevant information is missing

Comment: This could have been answered in 2 seconds by googling https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear in the beginning. Im a beginner. i am using a film festival api. this api works with film ids and it gives the json data according to that id. in that data there is film name, film url, film length etc. what i did is that i wrote all the ids under each country marker since I would like to show which movie is coming from which country. Now i can only see the ids in information windows, not the data that i want (filmName and filmUrl). Do you know how somehow to combine them ?

Comment: @JaredSmith I already have made the info window. The problem is that I want the content of the info window to be pull from a api

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the actual problem you're having (the one you stated in the comment above).

Comment: Also, do you want the data for each marker to be in the infowindow when you click on that marker? Or do you want one infowindow with the all the data? Infowindows you aren't really supposed to create a million different infowindows.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the code do you ever do anything with the information you receive back in your ajax call besides log it to the console. It does not magically appear in your marker objects.

You also seem rather unclear about the *asynchronous* part of ajax, the `var contentString = ...` part of your code actually runs *before* the code in your `for` loop. Additionally, every call to set the content of the infowindow looks like it overwrites the previous. Which means that even if you fix that, you're only going to see the results of the last ajax call.

Right now lets say you have 3 markers and each marker's `customInfo` array has 5 pieces of info. That's fifteen (15!) separate ajax requests. That's a lot. And I've done google maps applications with *thousands* of markers.

I highly recommend you create just one infowindow and do something more like this:

```
//@param filmID {Number}
//@param location {google.maps.LatLng}
function openInfoWindow(filmID, location) {

    //$.getJSON is a better choice here than $.ajax
    $.getJSON({
        url: apiURL,
        data: filmID,
        success: function(res) {

            //assumes a global infowindow variable and that your
            //google.maps.Map is called googlemap
            infowindow.setPosition(location); 
            infowindow.setContent(res.filmName_en + res.filmInfoURL);
            infowindow.open(googlemap);
        }
    });
}

ourMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {

        //in google maps event listeners, 'this' refers to the marker
        openInfoWindow(this.filmID, this.position);
    });
});
```

Now the ajax request only fires when the user clicks on a marker. If you wanted to cache the results of the ajax request (for instance you know that the API you're fetching data from always returns the same results for the same id) you could modify it slightly like this:

```
//@param filmID {Number}
//@param location {google.maps.LatLng}
var openInfoWindow = (function() {
    var cache = {};        

    return function(filmID, location) {
        if (cache[filmID]) {
            infowindow.setPosition(location); 
            infowindow.setContent(cache[filmID]);
            infowindow.open(googlemap);
        } else {
            $.getJSON({
                url: apiURL,
                data: filmID,
                success: function(res) {
                    var content = res.filmName_en + res.filmInfoURL;
                    cache[filmID] = content;
                    infowindow.setPosition(location); 
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(googlemap);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Now the code uses an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and stores the cache in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (nothing needs to change in the part where the listeners are attached).

Comment: thank you for your answer. One question before I ll try your suggestion, what is the parameter "id", in your example?

Comment: The id you feed to the API to get the info. Change to suit however you call it. I'll change it to filmID in the answer.